# conversion of regular string to json using cjson library

Tags: c, json, cjson

The code which was given in cJSON library converts from JSON String to JSON format.

Here is the code

```
/*
  Copyright (c) 2009 Dave Gamble

  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
  THE SOFTWARE.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

/* Parse text to JSON, then render back to text, and print! */
void doit(char *text)
{
    char *out;
    cJSON *json;

    json=cJSON_Parse(text);

    if (!json) {printf("Error before: [%s]\n",cJSON_GetErrorPtr());}
    else
    {
        out=cJSON_Print(json);
        cJSON_Delete(json);
        printf("%s\n",out);
        free(out);
    }
}

/* Read a file, parse, render back, etc. */
void dofile(char *filename)
{
    FILE *f;
    long len;
    char *data;

    f=fopen(filename,"rb");
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    len=ftell(f);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    data=(char*)malloc(len+1);
    fread(data,1,len,f);
    fclose(f);
    doit(data);
    free(data);
}

/* Used by some code below as an example datatype. */
struct record {const char *precision;double lat,lon;const char *address,*city,*state,*zip,*country; };

/* Create a bunch of objects as demonstration. */
void create_objects()
{
    cJSON *root,*fmt,*img,*thm,*fld;char *out;int i;    /* declare a few. */
    /* Our "days of the week" array: */
    const char *strings[7]={"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
    /* Our matrix: */
    int numbers[3][3]={{0,-1,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,1}};
    /* Our "gallery" item: */
    int ids[4]={116,943,234,38793};
    /* Our array of "records": */
    struct record fields[2]={
        {"zip",37.7668,-1.223959e+2,"","SAN FRANCISCO","CA","94107","US"},
        {"zip",37.371991,-1.22026e+2,"","SUNNYVALE","CA","94085","US"}};

    /* Here we construct some JSON standards, from the JSON site. */

    /* Our "Video" datatype: */
    root=cJSON_CreateObject();  
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "name", cJSON_CreateString("Jack (\"Bee\") Nimble"));
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "format", fmt=cJSON_CreateObject());
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(fmt,"type",     "rect");
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(fmt,"width",        1920);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(fmt,"height",       1080);
    cJSON_AddFalseToObject (fmt,"interlace");
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(fmt,"frame rate",   24);

    out=cJSON_Print(root);  cJSON_Delete(root); printf("%s\n",out); free(out);  /* Print to text, Delete the cJSON, print it, release the string. */

    /* Our "days of the week" array: */
    root=cJSON_CreateStringArray(strings,7);

    out=cJSON_Print(root);  cJSON_Delete(root); printf("%s\n",out); free(out);

    /* Our matrix: */
    root=cJSON_CreateArray();
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) cJSON_AddItemToArray(root,cJSON_CreateIntArray(numbers[i],3));

/*  cJSON_ReplaceItemInArray(root,1,cJSON_CreateString("Replacement")); */

    out=cJSON_Print(root);  cJSON_Delete(root); printf("%s\n",out); free(out);


    /* Our "gallery" item: */
    root=cJSON_CreateObject();
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "Image", img=cJSON_CreateObject());
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(img,"Width",800);
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(img,"Height",600);
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(img,"Title","View from 15th Floor");
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(img, "Thumbnail", thm=cJSON_CreateObject());
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(thm, "Url", "http:/*www.example.com/image/481989943");
    cJSON_AddNumberToObject(thm,"Height",125);
    cJSON_AddStringToObject(thm,"Width","100");
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(img,"IDs", cJSON_CreateIntArray(ids,4));

    out=cJSON_Print(root);  cJSON_Delete(root); printf("%s\n",out); free(out);

    /* Our array of "records": */

    root=cJSON_CreateArray();
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        cJSON_AddItemToArray(root,fld=cJSON_CreateObject());
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(fld, "precision", fields[i].precision);
        cJSON_AddNumberToObject(fld, "Latitude", fields[i].lat);
        cJSON_AddNumberToObject(fld, "Longitude", fields[i].lon);
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(fld, "Address", fields[i].address);
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(fld, "City", fields[i].city);
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(fld, "State", fields[i].state);
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(fld, "Zip", fields[i].zip);
        cJSON_AddStringToObject(fld, "Country", fields[i].country);
    }

/*  cJSON_ReplaceItemInObject(cJSON_GetArrayItem(root,1),"City",cJSON_CreateIntArray(ids,4)); */

    out=cJSON_Print(root);  cJSON_Delete(root); printf("%s\n",out); free(out);

}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    /* a bunch of json: */
    char text1[]={\n\"name\": \"Jack (\\\"Bee\\\") Nimble\", \n\"format\": {\"type\":       \"rect\", \n\"width\":      1920, \n\"height\":     1080, \n\"interlace\":  false,\"frame rate\": 24\n}\n}";
    char text2[]="[\"Sunday\", \"Monday\", \"Tuesday\", \"Wednesday\", \"Thursday\", \"Friday\", \"Saturday\"]";
    char text3[]="[\n    [0, -1, 0],\n    [1, 0, 0],\n    [0, 0, 1]\n   ]\n";
    char text4[]="{\n       \"Image\": {\n          \"Width\":  800,\n          \"Height\": 600,\n          \"Title\":  \"View from 15th Floor\",\n         \"Thumbnail\": {\n              \"Url\":    \"http:/*www.example.com/image/481989943\",\n               \"Height\": 125,\n              \"Width\":  \"100\"\n           },\n            \"IDs\": [116, 943, 234, 38793]\n       }\n }";
    char text5[]="[\n    {\n     \"precision\": \"zip\",\n   \"Latitude\":  37.7668,\n   \"Longitude\": -122.3959,\n     \"Address\":   \"\",\n  \"City\":      \"SAN FRANCISCO\",\n     \"State\":     \"CA\",\n    \"Zip\":       \"94107\",\n     \"Country\":   \"US\"\n     },\n    {\n     \"precision\": \"zip\",\n   \"Latitude\":  37.371991,\n     \"Longitude\": -122.026020,\n   \"Address\":   \"\",\n  \"City\":      \"SUNNYVALE\",\n     \"State\":     \"CA\",\n    \"Zip\":       \"94085\",\n     \"Country\":   \"US\"\n     }\n     ]";

    /* Process each json textblock by parsing, then rebuilding: */
    doit(text1);
    doit(text2);    
    doit(text3);
    doit(text4);
    doit(text5);

    /* Parse standard testfiles: */
/*  dofile("../../tests/test1"); */
/*  dofile("../../tests/test2"); */
/*  dofile("../../tests/test3"); */
/*  dofile("../../tests/test4"); */
/*  dofile("../../tests/test5"); */

    /* Now some samplecode for building objects concisely: */
    create_objects();

    return 0;
}
```

It gives error when i try to enter a regular string
 I want to convert Regular string to JSON format.

```
Such as below string

university name : abc
name : ram
age : 25
name" : sham
age : 24
name : rema
age : 26
```

should convert into Json format

```
{
   "university" : "abc",
   "name" : [ram, sham, rema]
   "age" : [25, 24, 26]
}
```

And if we are not able to convert from cJSON Library, which library should i use?

Comment: Code is such a mess to read..!!

Comment: @SKD you can refer the link https://github.com/kbranigan/cJSON/blob/master/test.c    for the code

Comment: Your JSON format is not valid JSON, nor is it a good data structure

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It was a sample actually i want to convert regular string into JSON format in c

Comment: Please provide a *minimal* example of the issue. Aside from argument about the JSON structure, you can't have `"name" : [ram, sham, rema]` as it is not valid JSON, you would need to have `"name" : ["ram", "sham", "rema"]`, i.e. in JSON strings need to be quoted.

Comment: I don't see the code that parses your given strings and generates json based on it. All the code given parses json lines and generates new jsons from hardcoded strings, and this is quite irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cJSON.h"

int main (void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    char field_name[32], value[32], *out;
    cJSON *root, *names, *ages;

    root  = cJSON_CreateObject();
    names = cJSON_CreateArray();
    ages  = cJSON_CreateArray();
    while(2 == fscanf(fp, " %31[^:]: %31[^\n]", field_name, value)){
        size_t len = strlen(field_name);
        while(field_name[len-1] == ' ')
            field_name[--len] = '\0';//end trim

        if(strcmp(field_name,  "university name") == 0)
            cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "university", cJSON_CreateString(value));
        if(strcmp(field_name,  "name") == 0)
            cJSON_AddItemToArray(names, cJSON_CreateString(value));
        if(strcmp(field_name,  "age") == 0)
            cJSON_AddItemToArray(ages, cJSON_CreateNumber(atof(value)));
    }
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "name", names);
    cJSON_AddItemToObject(root, "age", ages);
    fclose(fp);
    out = cJSON_Print(root);
    printf("%s\n",out);
    cJSON_Delete(root);
    free(out);

    return 0;
}
```